# How do i execute the code in Synchronous?

Tags: javascript, synchronization

```
var flag = displayMessage(message);             
if(flag=='true'){
    SaveAndGo(paramId,uniqueControlId);                             
}
```

wanted to check the if condition after the `displayMessage()` function call completes, currently its checking the if condition parallel. I have tried multiple options but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Post `displayMessage` code, please

Comment: its a confirmation dialog contains ok and cancle.. after capturing the value i am returning.

Comment: It would be better if you post it. It's hard to determine what wrong here. If It's merely confirmed dialog, `flag` returns a boolean not a string. In this case comparing `1` against `'true'` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

```
you could try to do something like this. based on your requirement you have to modify your code. look this :

var val = 10;
function displayMessage(callback){
    alert("first function execute");
    return callback();
}

var flag = 10;
displayMessage(function(){
    if(flag == val){
        alert("Now condition code execute");
    }
})
```